# datetime field overflow exception lazarus + mssql

Tags: sql-server, lazarus

Im trying to insert a timestamp into my mssql database.

i allready tried to set my field in the database to timestamp and to Datetime

```
query.Params.ParamByName('timestamp').AsDateTime:= Now;
```

this is the part i set the parameter for the insert statement

i get an datetime field overflow exception

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Build your FPC with debug information and step into the statement to see where it fails.

To build FPC with debug info use make clean all OPT=-g